# Change SKProduct/SKPayment delegate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I implement in-app purchases. I put all methods to separate class IAPHelper and for some reasons I wish to have SKProductsRequestDelegate in other class. Is there any way to change delegate to my other class insted of IAPHelper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if IAPHelper know the other class, sure :)

```
//In eg appDelegate
IAPHelper *helper = [[IAPHelper alloc] init];
helper.productsDelegate = self;
```

...

```
//in IAPHelper
-(void)setProductsHelper:(id)newHelper {
    self.productsRequest = newHelper;
}
```

---

for example